# Using NReco FFMpegConverter in an azure function or in a azure web job

Tags: ffmpeg, azure-functions, video-capture, azure-webjobs, nreco

Currently, I'm working on POC which converts h264 stream to MP4 file. I'm using NReco FFMpegConverter for that purpose and also use the Azure Cloud Service to host my service.
This Azure Cloud Service capture concurrent streams and convert the respective MP4 file. From the testing of this app so far I realize better to use Azure Function or Azure WebJobs to use only for the conversion of H264 stream to MP4 file. Then cloud service has more room to handle concurrent streams.

That I want to know, Is it possible to use NReco FFMpegConverter in Azure Function or Azure WebJobs without an issue? are there any special configurations to consider because FFmpeg runs in a separate thread with NReco FFMpegConverter?

Comment: Please refer to https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/dj6lqn/best_azure_service_to_run_ffmpeg_video_conversion/

Comment: Thanks, That link was helpful.

Comment: @Manojb86 Can you send your answers to the post and share it? This can better help more users in the forum.